# DART, How to perform "Greaterthan and No Equal" together?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to dart,
I was doing experiment with dart and suddenly got a  problem,

I am using this logic to obtain it, correct me if i am wrong.

```
int a = 8;
int b = 7;

if (!(a <= b)){
    print("A is Less");
}else{
    print("B is Less");
}
```

Comment: Can't you achieve that logic with a > b ?

Comment: sar , this example is for just usecase

Comment: That's what I'm asking if (! (a<=b)) is literally if (a > b) right ? If I missed something, could you please elaborate your question with specific usecase or an example scenario where you want to write the same logic?

Comment: Also what is the problem you are facing with above code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments on your question recommend ">" which is correct, but I thought I could help you understand your sample if construct and why it prints the opposite of what is accurate.

Any conditions inside an if must evaluate to a single boolean: true or false. In your if you test "a is less than or equal to b", which will yield 'true' or 'false', then you invert that boolean value with the boolean "!" not operator. Boolean 'not' changes true to false, and false to true.

Given the values you set for a and b, your if statement therefore checks if a is less than or equal to b, which is "false", then inverts that "false" to "true" using "!" not, and therefore prints "A is Less", which is an incorrect statement.

FWIW, your logic will also print "B is less" when a = b;